# How to naviagte to a screen after FutureBuilder returns data?

Tags: flutter, dart

When app is initalized using `Future` I get data from a remote `JSON` file.

Instead of `return`-in a `widget` when `FutureBuilder` has data, I want to navigate to a new screen.

The way I use now:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: getDataFromJsonFile(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return AnotherScreen();
        });
  }
```

Instead I want to navigate to a new screen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: getDataFromJsonFile(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/manatx");
        });
  }
```

Obviously, second code block causes error: `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build`

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why use future builder? You can directly use Future.then()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() will wait you Widget build to call the actions inside, look :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: getDataFromJsonFile(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          //Wait flutter finish build...
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            //When finish, call actions inside
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/manatx");
          });
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution was like this:

```
// create a variable of the Type of the your returned response from the Future
// in my case it was bool you can have any type returned from your Future
        bool isLogged = false;
    
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
// Create Future.delayed to wait until the returned response from the Future
// is stored in your variable
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () async {
          isLogged = await Prefrences.getUserSession() ?? false;
        });
// Execute your task here 
        Future.delayed(
            const Duration(
              milliseconds: 6500,
            ), () {
          if (isLogged == true) {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context,
              HomeScreen.id,
            );
          } else {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context,
              RegisterScreen.id,
            );
          }
        });
      }
```